# How to bypass on/off momentary switch?

Tags: power, switches, bypass

I have a Bluetooth receiver and was wondering if there was a way to have it turn on when power is plugged in without having to press the on switch?[image] the middle button is the on/off switch.

Comment: Thanks, kinda what I meant by “how”. So is there a way to figure out which ends I need to solder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the unit works the way you require by holding the power button as you power up the device then it is just a matter of short-circuiting the power switch.

A normally-open switch requires two terminals. Yours have four but these are just to provide mechanical security. Usually they are connected in pairs on either side of the switch. You can determine which is which using a multimeter on low-range resistance measurement. Then solder a bridge from a terminal of one pair to a terminal of the other.

Comment: Tried one combination with the multimeter and the receiver powered on...not sure if that’s supposed to happen. But I guess those two should be bridged.

Comment: You should never take resistance measurements on a powered circuit.

Comment: Got it, thanks. And the thing is, the receiver has a battery and I hadn’t removed it.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the buttons are connected in some sort of matrix, in which case you can NOT "just" short circuit the middle on.

You should try this first: keep the middle button pressed all the time, then switch the power on. Then, with the middle button still pressed, check if the other buttons still work.

Comment: Well holding down the middle button does switch the power on, but I tried it either way and the other buttons still work. I guess it’s not a matrix arrangement.